ngx-bootstrap support for Angular v17
Could you please let me know, when it will be supported with Angular version 17 ? As currently it is supported up-to Angular version 16.
Currently ngx-bootstrap is supported to Angular version 16. Anybody who migrate to the latest version of Angular which is version 17 now can get issues.

2 weeks ago we successfully migrated to v17.0.0 and recently to v18.0.0. Please note that version of ngx-bootstrap was bumped to fit angular major version so you need v12.0.0 for angular 17.0.0 and v18.0.0 for angular v18.0.0.
